# How is timezone EST different from EST5EDT?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

How different is EST from EST5EDT ? Isn't EST take into account DST?

I wrote a small java snippet to figure out the difference and output says EST5EDT takes in to account DST while EST does not

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST5EDT")); 
System.out.println("EST5EDT" +dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    /* prints EST5EDT2013-Apr-05 02:24:16.471 */  


dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")); 
System.out.println("EST "+dateFormat.format(new Date()));
   /*prints EST 2013-Apr-05 01:24:16.472 */
```

But the below snippet produced shocking output

```
System.out.println("EST5EDT offset "+TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST5EDT").getRawOffset()/(60*60*1000));
/* prints 5 instead of 4 (DST) */
```

Could someone please explain what exactly is happening here ? why is getRawOffset returning 5 instead of 4 ? How to get timezone offset with DST?

Comment: Avoid both `EST` and `EST5EDT` style identifiers whenever possible.  Use `America/New_York` and related identifiers instead.  [See Here](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.datetime/2009/03/msg7221.html) and the dup post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Isn't EST take into account DST?

No. By Definition EST is "Eastern Standard Time" Or UTC-5:00.

EDT is "Eastern Daylight Time" Or UTC-4:00.

It's a bit confusing, because for example, New York switches between EST and EDT, and Seattle switches between PST and PDT.

Sometimes people will say incorrectly "I'll call you 1pm EST" when they actually mean to say, " I'll call you 1pm Eastern time" which properly takes into account whether or not it's Daylight Savings.

This [wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) has a little more information.

> why is getRawOffset returning 5 instead of 4

[Timezone.getRawOffset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset%28%29) always returns the number of milliseconds for **standard** time, which is 5 * (60 * 60 * 1000)

Since the UTC Offset changes based of the day of the year (to account for DST), you'll need to use [getOffset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), and supply it the date you want to use.

Comment: Thanks that clarified getRawOffset doubt. I still have one doubt TimeZone currentTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
 Calendar currentDt = new GregorianCalendar(currentTimeZone, Locale.US);
 System.out.println("EST in daylight "+TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST").inDaylightTime(currentDt.getTime()) ); prints false ! why is that ?